# Carpet Installation on Concrete

Tags: concrete, floor, carpet

I am looking to put carpet down in a small 11x19 room that has a uneven concrete floor. I am aware that this isn't the best idea and will eventually cause uneven wear, but this is the short term solution I can afford at the moment.

Should I try and use tacks or just glue it down? My concern with tacks is that the floor has dips and that the carpet would stretch over them and leave a void. The glue makes more sense to me but I would like some sort of padding under the carpet and I'm not sure how to proceed with that.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: How much are the dips?  Carpet will stretch a bit and does not need to be stretch too tight, just enough to be flat(or follow) on the floor.

Comment: I'm no expert but I the dips are roughly 2 to 3 inches from wall to wall

Comment: Personally, I'd fill the dips to "as flat as I can get" first.  A 50 lb bag is only $30—you can't afford that add?

Comment: Sadly, Those dips are with me attempting to level it out as much as possible.